# Running a single block with multiple threads, CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I know that you should generally have at least 32 threads running per block on CUDA since threads are executed in groups of 32.  However I was wondering if it is considered an acceptable practice to have only one block with a bunch of threads (I know there is a limit on the number of threads).  I am asking this because I have some problems which require the shared memory of threads and synchronization across every element of the computation.  I want to launch my kernel like

`computeSomething<<< 1, 256 >>>(...)`

and just used the threads to do the computation.

Is this efficient to just have one block, or would I be better off just doing the computation on the cpu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you care about performance, it's a bad idea.

The principal reason is that a given threadblock can only occupy the resources of a single SM on a GPU.  Since most GPUs have 2 or more SMs, this means you're leaving somewhere between 50% to over 90% of the GPU performance untouched.

For performance, both of these kernel configurations are bad:

```
kernel<<<1, N>>>(...);
```

and

```
kernel<<<N, 1>>>(...);
```

The first is the case you're asking about.  The second is the case of a single thread per threadblock; this leaves about 97% of the GPU horsepower untouched.

In addition to the above considerations, GPUs are latency hiding machines and like to have a lot of threads, warps, and threadblocks available, to select work from, to hide latency.  Having lots of available threads helps the GPU to hide latency, which generally will result in higher efficiency (work accomplished per unit time.)

It's impossible to tell if it would be faster on the CPU.  You would have to benchmark and compare.  If all of the data is already on the GPU, and you would have to move it back to the CPU to do the work, and then move the results back to the GPU, then it might still be faster to use the GPU in a relatively inefficient way, in order to avoid the overhead of moving data around.